# React + Node.js или PHP отправка данных в Telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, telegram-bot, telegram, reactphp

Всем привет! 
Я написал приложение на Реакте, и оно довольно интересное, но проблема в том что я не занимаюсь Бекендом, пока что.. И я не знаю как правильно реализовать отправку формы в телеграм с помощью Node.js или PHP, 
ко может подсказать какие либо ресурсы либо статьи где про это можно почитать и узнать как решить эту задачу, или есть где то готовые решения ?

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: попробуйте эту библиотеку: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api

Comment: Cпасибо, воспользовался , работает )